# What are good options for long term parking at O'Hare Airport?

Tags: airports, automobiles, long-term, chicago, ord

I'm trying to figure out where to park for five days at or near Chicago's O'Hare Airport (Terminal 5).

I know there are on-airport parking lots E, F, G which are conveniently accessible to Terminal 5 via ATS train. Cheapest of which is lot F at $9/day, but it requires taking a bus to the ATS train.

The google search results for o'hare parking are a mess of ads. I did find some options including private economy lots [listed here](http://www.airportparkingreservations.com/) (if their shuttles even stop at terminal 5, you have to call them, not a huge deal but less convenient). The best reviewed off-airport spot I found was http://www.yelp.com/biz/preflight-airport-parking-schiller-park, it's $6/day but we have to call to get a shuttle to Terminal 5.

Where can I park for under $10/day that has the easiest access to Terminal 5?

Comment: Would a shuttle that takes to the terminal work as easiest?

Comment: Yep, frequent shuttle to Terminal 5 would be ideal. Especially if we didn't have to call it for pick-up.

Comment: So what's wrong with calling for pick up?   You walk off the plane and call for pick up the shuttle comes to pick you up.

Comment: It's just sounds less convenient to have to find the right place to call and wait, with so many options I figure there's got to be some company that offers constant shuttles.

Comment: So you expect a parking lot under 10$ a day with frequent buses going directly (no connection) to Terminal 5? Isn't it asking a bit too much?

Comment: @Vince why would it be too much to ask? there are lots of similar offers.

Comment: It's mostly the connection-free itinerary that is hard to find. Taking a plane usually means multiple "connections" : from home to the airport parking, to the terminal (because many airports are large areas), from check-in to boarding, from boarding room to airplane, and then from the plane to the customs, to the luggage area, to the airport exit, and then to your final destination. You go for a bit and wait all the time, so expecting a connection-free itinerary is complicated and makes little sense to me, no matter the airport.

Answer (score 3):

### Parking Lots ... Parking Lots Everywhere

Parking around Chicago O'Hare Airport seems to be a highly requested service, considering the number of options that can be found on the web. The reason behind this is probably due to the lack of convenience of having to catch a train from the economy parking lots to the terminal, or to the lack of cheap (≤ 10$/day) parking spots. To be fair, convenience has a price. Therefore cheap convenient parking is probably somewhat of an oxymoron.

#### Parkings Including Shuttle Bus To/From the Terminal Building

Looking around the web I stumbled upon [this website](http://parking.chicago.com/2013/01/09/ohare-airport-parking-guide/), which offers a detailed list of parking services neighbouring the airport. The cheapest options tend to be further away from the terminals, and offer direct-connection shuttles, running at frequencies between once every 5 or 10 minutes. The rates seem to oscillate at around 10$/day, give or take a few bucks. These include a city tax and a county tax which each add up to something around 0.50$ per day, i.e. 1$/day in total. See the figure below for a dummy 5-day (`5 * 24h`) booking with [this company picked at random](http://www.parknjetchicago.com/):

[image: Random booking]

For completeness sake, I just discovered [SpotHero](http://spothero.com/), which is a mapping tool which can be used to locate parking spots by geographical position. Using `O'Hare Airport, Chicago, IL` as a search term yields [the following map of results](http://spothero.com/chicago/ohare-parking/?latitude=41.97167723856985&longitude=-87.86855252368161&start_date=06-15-2015&start_time=1230PM&end_date=06-20-2015&end_time=1230PM&q=O%27Hare%2BAirport%252C%2BChicago%252C%2BIL&rlat=41.9731735112&rlng=-87.8810269894&zoom=13). Aside from the airport parking, the rates retrieved by SpotHero seem to be oscillate between 8$-10$/day. Most of the services offer shuttles to/from the airport.

All in all, the results of these searches show that there are *plenty* of parking options in and around Chicago O'Hare Airport. Indeed, owning parking lots seems to be a very profitable business in Chicago. **Prices across different services might vary by a few bucks but generally speaking they are all similarly equipped: 24h access, shuttle to/from the airport, car wash service, etc.**

Having said this, convenience and cheapness are somewhat subjective parameters. It will therefore be up to you to pick the option which suits you better.

Answer (score 1):

If parking offsite is still too pricey for long term trip, you might want to try renting a car one-way and doing it to and from the airport. I did this on a recent trip flying out of another region and it saved me a ton of money. If you don't like that idea then there are some other good suggestions for ways to save money on parking on this [O'Hare parking page](http://airportparkinghelper.com/ord-chicago-ohare-parking-rates/)